# SVG not working in StoryBook setup for React

Tags: reactjs, svg, storybook

I have a SVG in my react component and the component is working fine. Now, I have setup the storybook for that component. But I am facing an issue saying `'Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('static/media/utils/assets/Logo.svg')` is not a valid name.'.
I am storing my SVG under `rootDirectory/utils/assets/Logo.svg` folder.  Here are the component and storybook files:

```
header.jsx

import React from 'react';
import { styles } from './headerStyles';
import Logo from '../../utils/assets/Logo.svg';

const Header = () => {
  const classes = styles();
  return (
    <>
       <Logo className={classes.Logo} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

```
header.stories.js

import React from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';

export default {
  title: 'Header',
  component: Header,
};

const Template = (args) => <Header {...args} />;

export const mainHeader = Template.bind({});

mainHeader.args = {};
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app` to help build your app?

Comment: No using `nextjs` and `webpack`. it is server side rendered

Comment: Worth a shot I guess, try `import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../../utils/assets/Logo.svg';`.

Comment: if I do that, I am facing `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.` issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted the SVG into a react component and used that in `header.jsx`. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change the existing webpack rule.
I changed the standard webpack rule to exclude the directory with the assets folder where the svgs are located.

```
config.module.rules = config.module.rules.map((rule) =>
  rule.test.test(".svg") ? { ...rule, exclude: /assets.+\.svg$/ } : rule
);

config.module.rules.unshift({
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
});
```